# gradle 4.6, Junit 5, jacoco test coverage report is empty

Tags: gradle, jacoco, junit5

I’m trying to create a new project with grade 4.6 Junit 5 and jacobo code coverage. I used the junit sample and added the jacoco sample provided by gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}
```

When I run

```
gradle build jacocoTestReport
```

the generated report is empty. Can some one provide a minimal example?
[image: jacoco report]

Comment: The sample explains how to specify a jacoco configuration that is specific to this test task. Do you really want/need that? If you remove the whole jacoco configuration from the test task and thus use the default settings, everything will probably run fine.

Comment: You're probably right. I do not need that configuration.